# appending library name to CFLAGS in makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to add $(STATIC_LIB) while compiling some object files using make.

But,modifying CFLAGS this way:

```
tests: CFLAGS +=$(STATIC_LIB)
tests: $(OBJECT_FILES)
      echo "Do something"
```

puts the library before source files. How do i put the library after the names of any files, at the end of the CFLAGS?

Instead of this:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc/lcthw -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  build/liblcthw.a    tests/list_tests.c   -o tests/list_tests
```

i want:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc/lcthw -rdynamic -DNDEBUG      tests/list_tests.c  -o tests/list_tests build/liblcthw.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default rules to link your program, then libraries should be added to the `LDLIBS` makefile variable not to `CFLAGS`.  `CFLAGS` are for *compiler* flags, not linker flags.

If you've written your own rules to do the linking, then we can't answer your question because you didn't show us the rule you wrote to link.